# Best approach to keep/clean localStorage/session on tab/window closed

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, local-storage, token

I found plenty Q&A about how to execute scripts or alerts when closing the tab or window. However, suppose that you authenticate and you want to hold your JWT in the localStorage (LS). As long as your token is alive you are gonna retrieve it from LS.

I want to remove my token explicitly when I close the tab or the window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>)

I came up with the idea to define a script on the beforeunload of my page like this:

```
<script>
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event){
   window.localStorage.removeItem("myID");
});
</script>
```

But then I realized that on refresh <kbd>F5</kbd> the onbeforeunload will execute and I will clear the LS.

Then I came up with this solution

```
<script>
var clearLocalStorage = true;
$(window).on('keydown', function(event){
   if(event.keyCode == 116 ||  //F5
        (k == 16 && k == 17 && k == 82) ||  //Shift + Ctrl + R
        (k == 17 && k == 82)){  //Ctrl + R
      clearLocalStorage = false;
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event){
   if(clearLocalStorage){
      window.localStorage.removeItem("myID");
   }
});
</script>
```

This works well with <kbd>F5</kbd> because it does not clear my LS, but if I do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, it will lose my token from LS.

After login I want to keep my token on the LS then....

1. On refresh by any means it should hold always the token from LS even if further you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Click on the URL address of the browser and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to reload the page.
3. Clear only when user close the tab or window. If you reopen the tab you will need to go again to login page.

I already wanted to control the LS at the moment of closing the window on the onClose event as follows, but it didn't work as I queried the LS on the console of the developers tools I could see that the token is still there.

```
<script>
   window.onClose = function(){
      window.localStorage.removeItem("myID");
   }
</script>
```

I wonder what would be the best approach to manage the LS and token sessions when refreshing and/or closing the tab or window using jquery, jwt, html only and angularjs 1.5?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try a timed event:

```
var clearLocalStorage = true;
$(window).on('keydown', function(event){
   if(event.keyCode == 116 ||  //F5
        (k == 16 && k == 17 && k == 82) ||  //Shift + Ctrl + R
        (k == 17 && k == 82)){  //Ctrl + R
      clearLocalStorage = false;
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event){
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(clearLocalStorage)
       window.localStorage.removeItem("myID");
    else
      window.localStorage.persistItem("myID"); // make a persistent item in case
    }, 10); // I don't recommend anything above 100ms
});
```